# Installing Laravel 4 Powerpack breaks code in SessionServiceProvider?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-4, packagist

After I use `composer update` with L4 powerpack requirement in `composer.json`, it fetches it with no problems. Then I update `providers` and `aliases` arrays in app.php, but when I use `HTML::script(...)` I get the following:

```
ErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: domain in C:\Users\Dartanjan\Documents\web\big\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider.php line 124
```

I also tried a different package, but I get the same.

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not because of the l4 powerpack, but because of  newly changes in laravel, download the newest version of laravel and look for the differences in the app/session file

Comment: Btw, if someone is looking for the exact link to the latest develop version, here it is: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/develop.zip